# How to increase scrolling performance of large JTable?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

The following is a rudimentary sample of scrolling with large amounts of data and 1 Renderer.

With 7,000 row and 10 columns, the slow performance is visible when you used the mouse to drag the scroll button up/down quickly. This is with the Renderer simply returning the same string.

If you edit the renderer in the example to uncomment the IF (and else if) statements which does extra work on the data in the first 3 columns, you will notice the performance get significantly worse as you move the scroll button up/down quickly.

```
//Remove these comments from the code.
//  if (vColIndex == 0)
//        setText("...
//  else if (vColIndex == 1)
//      setText("...
//  else if (vColIndex == 2)
//      setText("...
```

The following command was used in an attempt to improve performance :

```
scrollpane.getViewport().setBackingStoreEnabled(true);
```

Since the above is deprecated, the following command was used with all 3 available options but there still was no improvement.

```
  scrollpane.getViewport().setScrollMode(2);
```

Here is the actual code.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;



public class RendererTest
{
    static JTable table;
    TableColumn tcol;

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception 
  {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a Custom Cell Reanderer!");
      frame.setSize(800, 800);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      int rows = 7000;
      int cols = 10;
      Object data[][] = new Object[rows][cols] ;
      for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
      {
          for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
          {
              data[i][j] = "Hello World";
          }
      }
      String columns [] = {"Colum 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5",
              "Column 6","Column 7","Column 8","Column 9","Column 10"};
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);
      table = new JTable(model);
      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
//    scrollpane.getViewport().setBackingStoreEnabled(true);
//    scrollpane.getViewport().setScrollMode(2);
//    System.out.println(scrollpane.getViewport().getScrollMode());
      scrollpane.getViewport().setScrollMode(2);
      table.setDoubleBuffered(true);
      scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 1000));
      scrollpane.setViewportView(table);

      panel.add(scrollpane);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

    int vColIndex = 0;
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(++vColIndex).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
  }
}

class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
    setText(value.toString());
//      if (vColIndex == 0)
//            setText("<html><pre><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffff00><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffff00><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT></pre></html>");    
//      else if (vColIndex == 1)
//          setText("<html><pre><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffff00><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffff00><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=bebebe><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT></pre></html>");
//      else if (vColIndex == 2)
//          setText("<html><pre><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffb500><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffb500><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ff00ff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=00ffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffb500><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffffff><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffb500><B>?</B></FONT><FONT FACE='Monospaced' fontsize=16 COLOR=ffb500><B>?</B></FONT></pre></html>");
    setToolTipText((String) value);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Are there any other built-in options to try?

How can you tell when the slower performance is expected and you are hitting max performance?

Are there any tools other than JVisualVM to help pinpoint the slowness?

Comment: Make your cell renderer extend [DefaultTableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) instead of extending JLabel directly.  DefaultTableCellRenderer has a lot of optimizations.

Comment: Thanks. That actually helped in this scenario.

Comment: It might also help to extend [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) directly, instead of using DefaultTableModel.  DefaultTableModel uses Vectors, which enforce synchronization on every access, which may be a source of extra overhead.  Since table models have to be accessed on the AWT event dispatch thread anyway, thread safety has no value.  Typically, a custom model keeps table items in a private ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately the actual code uses a Model that tied to other object that can't be modified. I am restricted to working with the Renderers and extending the DefaultTableCellRenderer helped. Curious to know more specifics. Is there a link that discusses these optimizations?

Comment: The [implementation note in the DefaultTableCellRenderer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#override) describes the reasons for overriding several methods:  in most cases, component hierarchy processing is needless overhead that doesn’t apply to a cell renderer.

Comment: Per that link it reads :"So this class overrides the validate, invalidate, revalidate, repaint, and firePropertyChange methods to be no-ops..." does this mean if I am working with some 3rd party renderer that happens to extend JLabel and it causes a performance issue, will I be able to override those same methods and make them a no-op to fix it?

Comment: I tried doing the same and it worked. Wasn't sure what to do for the isOpaque() so just skipped it but overriding the others seems to have helped.

Comment: The answer is yes, probably.  You can see what DefaultTableCellRenderer.isOpaque does in [the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.java#l274), though I honestly don’t know the legal issues incurred by copying JDK code.